# What went wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Consider the thermodynamic partition function $Z = \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\beta E_i}$.

We derive the relation
\begin{equation}
  \langle E \rangle
  = \sum_{i=0}^\infty E_i P_i
  = \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{i=0}^\infty E_i e^{-\beta E_i}
  = -\frac{1}{Z} \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\beta E_i}
  = -\frac{1}{Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}
\end{equation}

Formally, this looks similar to $ -\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta}$

However, if we actually compute this latter expression, we get
\begin{equation}
  - \frac{\partial \ln \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\beta E_i}} {\partial \beta}
  = - \frac{\partial \ln e^{\sum_{i=0}^\infty -\beta E_i}} {\partial \beta}
  = \frac{\partial \beta  \sum_{i=0}^\infty  E_i} {\partial \beta}
  = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  E_i
\end{equation}
Which is a nonsense answer.

Could someone please help explain what went wrong?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)#Calculating_the_thermodynamic_total_energy

Comment: $e^{\sum x_i}\neq \sum e^{x_i}$

Comment: @Sobanoodles   But ln (e^x + e^y) = ln e ^(x+y) = x+y

Comment: Btw, how do I add latex for comments?

Comment: just type equations inside dollar signs for TeX typesetting. Regarding the question, $e^x+e^y \neq e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$

Comment: Ah, crap. I just saw it. $ln a + ln b = ln ab$, but $ln (a + b) \neq ln ab$. Sorry guys.

Comment: @Rascalniikov Yes.  Another way to see it is to realize that what Soba noodles says is also correct.  They are all related.

Comment: @mike          Yes, indeed. I made the mistake by misdoing the arithmetic with the logarithms, not with the sums and exponentials, however. A mistake which persists from the days I hated math... Hopefully it will be the last time. Anw, thank you guys very much for the help.

Comment: @Rascalniikov If you say so.  I just want to be sure that you're not going to go around replacing $e^x + e^y$ with $e^{x+y}$.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At one point you replace
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\beta E_i}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
e^{-\sum_{i=0}^\infty \beta E_i}.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
This is wrong.  The quantity that *could* be replaced by (2) would be
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\beta E_i}.
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Typically, there's no simple transformation of a sum of exponentials.